# JavaScript Variables and User Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-input

Situation:

Currently I have a search box utilizing jQuery’s autocomplete plugin that allows the user to search for a sport’s team and then once found select on a submit button where it appends the team as a list item (preferable functionality would be when the user clicks on the actual team to append the item but at this point I am unsure of how to apply an on click function to the autocomplete drop down – suggestions welcome).

I am looking for a way to associate the newly appended list item to a predefined class or id so that certain formatting and displays are applied to the appended list item as soon as it is appended.Basically the user can search for any team in the NHL, NFL, etc. and I need to pair text colors and logos with them depending on which team they select - but the logos will appear separately in the body not in the list.

Example Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>TEST</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<style type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="ui-widget">
        <input id="tags" type="text" placeholder="Search Teams"/>
            <input id="submit" type="submit"/>
    </div>
        <ul class="target">
        </ul>

<script>

    $(function() {
            var availableTeams = [
                "Boston Red Sox",
                "New England Patriots",
                "Boston Celtics",
                "Boston Bruins",
                "New England Revolution"
            ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTeams
        });
    });

    $('#submit').click(
        function() {
            var term = $('#tags').val();
                $('.target').append("<li>"+term+"</li>");
                }
            );
</script>       

</body>

</html>
```

I have tried using a combination of if statements and document.getElementById to try and alter the html content but I cannot piece my thoughts together.

My thoughts:

if (tags == "Boston Red Sox") {
    Then append "Boston Red Sox" with specific formatting as a list Item and corresponding logo below. 
} else {
    dont do anything 
}

http://jsfiddle.net/kumcav30/ (ideally when appended it would resemble something like the fiddle). Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery will let you create elements and alter them before you add them to the document. So you could do something like:

```
$('#submit').click(
    function() {
        var term = $('#tags').val();
            var newelement = $("<li>"+term+"</li>");

            if (term == "Boston Red Sox") {
                newelement.addClass("your-class");
                //whatever else you need to do
            }

            $('.target').append(newelement);
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have been able to implement this method pretty quickly and this seems to do what I need it to do but as I mentioned above I need it to also generate the corresponding shape and logo in the body which has separate CSS. It looks like I will have to write some additional onclick javascript to handle the shape/logo.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/gdersubt Just for reference to both of you @TheF. As seen by my fiddle, the shapes are currently hard coded.

Comment: Using Style.display='inline' combined with some other default styling and some jQuery/Javascript did the trick. Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 0):

How about a for loop?

```
$(function(){    

var availableTeams = [
    "Boston Red Sox",
    "New England Patriots",
    "Boston Celtics",
    "Boston Bruins",
    "New England Revolution"
];

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTeams
});

var availableLogos = [
    "redSox",
    "patriots",
    "celtics",
    "bruins",
    "englandRevolution"
];

function teamstyle(term){
    var l = availableTeams.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++){
        if (term == availableTeams[i]){
            var newelement = "<li class="+ availableLogos[i] +">"+term+"</li>"
            $('.target').append(newelement);
        }
    }
}

$('#submit').click(function() {
    var term = $('#tags').val();
    teamstyle(term);
});

});
```

then you could use css like:

```
.redSox {color: red; background: url('path/to/logo.png');}
.bruins {color: yellow;}
....
```

Your question is a bit confusing. consider narrowing it down to what you want to achieve (:

Comment: I like the idea of using this method but I have only had partial success. I was able to append items to the list and it would apply formatting, but unfortunately once any subsequent list item is appended, all prior list items take on the last item’s formatting. Similarly to the method below, I have not been able to generate the corresponding team logo so I may need to write some separate JavaScript to do this - shouldn't be too difficult given the code you both have produced for me.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gdersubt/1/ Here is a working fiddle with the for loop. You really should be able to style the teams the way you want using the css classes from `availableLogos`.
Hope this works for you